# How to detect when MvxListView is bound and has loaded its bindings?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I've Inherted MvxListView to my CustomMvxListView where I dos something with the visualization when a child has been added or removed.

It works great but can be laggy when many items get bound.

Is there a way to detect when Mvx view controls are bound and loaded there first bound data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good solution myself;
To track Itemsource changes in Android in a ListView you can use a DataSetObserver.

like:

```
    internal class MyObserver : DataSetObserver
{
    private readonly object view;

    public MvxListViewNonScrollableObserver(ViewToTrack view)
    {
        tView = view;
        DoSomething():
    }

    public override void OnChanged()
    {
        base.OnChanged();
        DoSomething():
    }
}
```

Add it to a ListView by:

```
    class MyMvxListView : MvxListView
{
    protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {
        base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        itemsourceObserver = new MyObserver(this);
        Adapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(itemsourceObserver);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        if (itemsourceObserver != null)
        {
            Adapter.UnregisterDataSetObserver(itemsourceObserver);
            itemsourceObserver = null;
        }
        base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
```

DoSomething() get raised after load and on every itemsource change.